# Spring inside war cannot find classpath resource in an inner jar file

Tags: spring, tomcat, classpath, war

I have a project organized like this:

```
core
  -- /src/main/resources/company/config/spring-config.xml
webapp
  -- /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
```

The webapp depends on `core.jar`, which is included correctly in `WEB-INF/lib` when I deploy.

In `web.xml` I have:

```
<param-value>
    /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
</param-value>
```

And in `applicationContext.xml` I have:

```
<import resource="classpath:/company/config/spring-config.xml" />
```

But when I run, I get this error:

```
2012-10-04 20:03:39,156 [localhost-startStop-1] springframework.web.context.ContextLoader ERROR: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/company/config/spring-config.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [company/config/spring-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [company/config/spring-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
....
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [company/config/spring-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
... 36 more
```

When `spring-config.xml` is in webapp, everything works fine.

I noticed the leading `/` is removed from some of the errors on the stack trace, and I wonder if this has anything to do with it.

Also, I am (unfortunately) using Spring 2.5, if that matters.

Comment: remove / from /company/config/spring-config.xml and then check

Comment: @Satya: Thanks, I tried that, I get the same result.

Comment: @JBCP - it may not work when you remove the leading slash, because you have some additional problem, but it definitely will not work with the leading slash. You may also want to read this article, which may help: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2007/05/17/using-classpath-vs-classpath-when-loading-spring-resources/

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I get the exact same stack trace without the /, not a different one. I will check out the link and report back if it helps.

Comment: The article @GreyBeardedGeek recommends suggests using "classpath*:", which results in a different error (bean not found). I suspect that is because one of the side effects of classpath* is that an error is not thrown if no resources are found. I still have not solved this problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For future reference, I figured out the problem after much debugging. It turns out Eclipse was building my "core" library as a jar, but with a web application package layout, so instead of my resource being located here:

```
/company/config/spring-config.xml
```

it was located here:

```
/WEB-INF/company/config/spring-config.xml
```

which caused the problem. I had checked the jar a few times before, but had never noticed the sneaky "/WEB-INF" hiding in plain sight.

Removing the project and re-importing it into Eclipse (via the Maven pom.xml file) was not enough to fix the problem.

I had to manually delete the Eclipse-specific .project, .classpath, and .settings files. When I did that and re-imported the project everything was fixed.

The moral of the lesson is: **ALWAYS** check your resource paths when the exception says "File Not Found".